# SSIS Derived column trailing zeros

Tags: ssis

Im having a issue with a Derived column. Basically I have a flat file source which contains delimited data.

Some of my columns are currencies and the data is saved in a strange format (older systems tend to do it this way).

Anyways, The data is saved as such: 00030.200, 0123.410,0002231.210

I need to convert these strings to Currency DT_CY. 
I've tried direct casts using all the difference numerical types but they all fail (Not sure if the leading or trailing zeros causing it)

So my question is simple. What expression can I use in a derived column to remove the leading and trailing zeros. Note that the data is not the same length all the time so can't exactly do left/right substring options.

Any help?

Tx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could have done it this way, using a derived column:

```
Replace(Ltrim(Replace(dataToConvert, "0", " ")), " ", "0")
```

Basically, you convert zeros to white spaces to take benefits of Ltrim function.

I founded this solution [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/f39f8911-a5cf-4aab-8c18-3324eae64533/).

Here is an example of how it will proceed:
(Let's say we want to convert 0040.300. 
For the purpose, we can display the number as: |0|0|4|0|.|3|0|0| to see how Replace statement affects our data)

Basically, the conversion of 0040.300 will operate this way:

- inner Replace: | | |4| |.|3| | |    ('0' become space)
- Ltrim: |4| |.|3| | | (left spaces are trimmed)
- outer Replace:|4|0|.|3|0|0| (spaces become '0')

So we end up with 40.300.

Comment: Isn't this going to replace zeros in the middle of the strings? Example 012301.11 Is this not going to come out as  1231.11. Not sure, just asking.

Comment: Ok, this makes alot of sense. I'm marking yours as answer because even though my answer below would've worked as well, it's not a SSIS best practice to write code for a simple thing like this. Tx for your help.

Comment: it is also replacing the 0 from 0.something sorry for re floating this.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I found the answer myself by playing with a "Script Component" and using the following code to remove all Leading Spaces for all Properties passed in:

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    var rowProperties = Row.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (var rowColumn in rowProperties)
    {           

        if (rowColumn.PropertyType == typeof(System.String))
        {          
            var rowValue = rowColumn.GetValue(Row, null);    
            rowColumn.SetValue(Row, rowValue.ToString().TrimStart('0'), null);
        }
    }        
}
```