# SSIS: Add decimal 2 LEN from right

Tags: ssis, expression, decimal

I am importing data from a flat file
In a flat file data comes without decimal like 00000490700 for 4907,00.

I've tried data transformation as in:

(DT_DECIMAL,2)(SUBSTRING(column,1,LEN(column)-2)+"."+RIGHT(column,2))

However; the result I get is still 490700,00

So, what I want to do is to add a decimal with 2 "Steps" from the right.
NOT to add two extra zero's after the decimal.

I probably should divide it by 100, but how can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSIS Derived column trailing zeros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16462547/ssis-derived-column-trailing-zeros)

Comment: Thanks for the help, however my issue isn't concerning the zeros. More of how can I add decimal into current number and not add two zeros after the decimal. Ex. 490700 should be 4907,00 and not 490700,00

Comment: Divide it by 100. "SSIS-Task: Derived Column" => "Expression: ColumnName / 100" => Under "Derived Column" select the appropriate column (ColumnName) to be replaced. If you need "Decimal,2", then put a cast into the "Expression"-input-box

Comment: Thanks, solved it like this: (DT_DECIMAL,2)((DT_DECIMAL,2)(SUBSTRING(Column,1,LEN(column)-2)+"."+RIGHT(column,2))/100.0)

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it like this:

(DT_DECIMAL,2)((DT_DECIMAL,2)(SUBSTRING(Column,1,LEN(column)-2)+"."+RIGHT(column,2))/100.0)